# How do I refresh the page when a user is routed in Ionic 5 using Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, ionic5

I'm on `Page B` and I route user to `Page A` when an action is performed in `Page B`. How do I refresh the `Page A` so that I can get fetch the new data. I wrote a service to fetch data which I am calling in `Page A`'s constructor like below.

**Page A**

`Page A`'s constructor

```
data: any = [];

constructor(
   private dataService: DataService,
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
 ){
   this.route.params.subscribe(val => {
     this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res => this.data = response);
  });
}
```

**Page B**

In `Page B`, I'm performing a button action to route to `Page A`. With this, I was expecting it to refresh the `Page A` whenever this button action is performed. Could anyone please help?

```
onSubmit() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {
    skipLocationChange: true
  }).then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['page-a']);
  });
}
```

Also, I do have this `onSameUrlNavigation` set to `reload` in the **app-routing.module.ts** file.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: You haven't shown how the new data is generated or handled. Angular will not just refresh page unless it detects a change.

Comment: So, I was pushing the data that the service fetches into an array when page is loaded in `Page A`. how do i detect that change in that array as I'm adding new data in `Page B`? Would passing the data from Page A to Page B through service would be a good approach? as they are both individual components. Really looking for help, could you please suggest? @JohnPeters

Comment: The variable in page A is the key. It must change to get new view. How are you changing it? Directly from B? Events work best for inter component communication. Read this article https://dev.to/jwp/the-angular-event-service-ech

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

You move the code that you wrote in the page A constructor into ngOnInit() and then check

Answer (score 1):

You move your code into **ionViewDidEnter()**  which is written into the **constructor(){/*Move this code/*}** and try to navigate one page to another.